# PHP: Preg_Match_All strange behaviour

Tags: php, regex, recursion, preg-match-all

I have a pattern being matched to a large string, using preg_match_all, it is getting the correct matches just fine however it then seems to go into each of those matches and try to find more matches, and then into each of those and stops when it's finally on an empty string. Sounds like some sort of recursion but I don't need and don't want this, is there a way to stop it?

Thank you for any help!

```
function getCategories($source)
{
    $categories = array();

    $pattern = "~<span class=.*\n<table class=.*\n<tr>\n<th.*\n<.th>\n<th.*\n<.th>\n<th.*\n<.th>\n<th.*\n<.th>\n<th.*\n<.th>\n<th.*\n<.th><.tr>\n(<tr id=.*\n(.*\n){6}<.td><.tr>(<.table>)?\n)*~";

    preg_match_all($pattern, $source, $categories);

    return $categories;
}

$categories = getCategories($source);

print_r($categories);
```

Comment: Yes, you fix it by not using regexes on html, and switching to DOM/xpath instead.

Comment: What an ugly regex ... Just use something like [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

Comment: I've pretty much finally got my code working to some degree, I don't have the time to spend trying to understand new classes and rewriting it all, is there no way to just remove this recursive nature of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is because there are multiple instances where you use `.*` terms.

The term can correspond to any length of string and can span across multiple tr tags in the example.

You need to use the non-greedy version `.*?`. that should do the trick.

Note: As suggested, the best approach for doing what you are attempting will be to parse the DOM structure as DOMElement or XML

Comment: I understand it wasn't the nicest way to form my expression, mainly did it that way because it works and I'm too lazy to write it properly, however even though it can form matches when it goes into each match, I don't want it going there at all, even if I made the regex perfect, it'd still create a 1th element full of empty strings.

I'll heed the advice next time I need to get HTML from a site! Thank you all for the recommendations.

Comment: I've solved this by simply returning the 0th element(array of the stuff I wanted) instead of the whole array of arrays. It simply ignores the rest... Don't like wasting memory that way but I'll deal with it. I'll give you the marked answer.

Comment: Is the `.*` replacement with `.*?` working? If not, specify what is actually working and mark that as the answer.